# Importing csv file into python using pandas in 3.9 but it failed "file not found"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.9

I have tried every method and checked my file path many times.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv(r'Users\Desktop\HG4070 ICE\VTLN04.csv')
```

could it be due to the source file location? I'm not sure how to do it in python (I'm new) Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing drive letter in the path (It should be `C:`):

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\HG4070 ICE\VTLN04.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is
Load the file in the same directory of the python file working directory
Then just load the csv file with its name
`pd.read_csv("file_name.csv")`